# early JS Rock paper scissors game

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make a rock-paper.. game but it seems that the code works only when i have a tie. I've probably messed it up on the way down.Also i want to ask if the number on the prompt window that you fill in is a string or a number ?
Any bit of help appreciated.Thanks !

```
// rock beats scissors (1 beats 3)
// paper beats rock (2 beats 1)
// scissors beat paper (3 beat 2)


 var player1= prompt("Player ONE, choose (1) for rock, (2) for paper, (3) for scissors");
 var player2 = prompt("Player TWO, choose (1) for rock, (2) for paper, (3) for scissors");

 function game (player1,player2)
 {

    if (player1===player2){
    alert("its a tie");
    }
    else
    { 
      if (player1+player2==="4")
      {
        if(player1==="1"){
        alert("Rock beats Scissors, Player one wins");
        }else {
        alert("Rock beats Scissors, Player Two wins");
        }

      }
      if (player1+player2==="3")
        {
         if (player1==="1"){
            alert("paper beats rock, player One wins");
         }else {
          alert ("paper beats rock, player Two wins");
          }
         }  
      if (player1+player2==="5")
        {
          if (player1==="3"){
            alert("scissors beats paper, Player One wins");
            }else{
            alert("scissors beats papaer, player Two wins");
            }

        }
    }
};
game(player1,player2);
```

Comment: read over your 'paper beats rock' block v. carefully - it needs switching

Comment: To find the type, just use the function typeof, like this  alert(typeof(player1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're concatenating strings, not adding numbers, so your `player1+player2==="3"` would actually produce `12` or `21`. You want to convert the string to a number first.

Place this code at the top of the else block of your tie check.

```
player1 = parseInt(player1);
player2 = parseInt(player2);
```

As an extension, you will want to sanitise the player input to make sure that it only contains digits, as this method will fail if anything other than a numeric string is passed.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing string concatenation and not integral maths on your player1..2 vars.

Notice that you will need to change your comparisons as well, not just parsing the strings to ints.

Try:

```
 var player1= parseInt(prompt("Player ONE, choose (1) for rock, (2) for paper, (3) for scissors"));
 var player2 = parseInt(prompt("Player TWO, choose (1) for rock, (2) for paper, (3) for scissors"));

 function game (player1,player2)
 {

  if (player1===player2){
    alert("its a tie you mofos");
  }
  else
  { 
    if (player1+player2===4)
    {
      if(player1===1){
        alert("Rock beats Scissors, Player one wins");
      }else {
        alert("Rock beats Scissors, Player Two wins");
      }
    }
    if (player1+player2===3)
    {
      if (player1===1){
        alert("paper beats rock, player One wins");
      }else {
        alert("paper beats rock, player Two wins");
      }
    }  
    if (player1+player2===5)
    {
      if (player1===3){
        alert("scissors beats paper, Player One wins");
      }else{
        alert("scissors beats papaer, player Two wins");
      }
    }
  }
};
game(player1,player2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Ruirize wrote, there is also another mistake:

In the lines `player1+player2==="4"` you are trying to add two integers and then compare them to a string.

The `===` operator does not just compare the value, but also the type. When you compare an integer with a string, it will return false.

Either use the `==` comperator, where the number 4 is equal to the string "4", or compare to the number 4:

```
player1+player2 === 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Hope it helps!

```
--javascript code for rock, paper, scissors...--

var userChoice = prompt("Please type in your choice : rock , paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34)
{
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if(computerChoice <= 0.67)
{
    computerChoice = "paper";
}
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function (userChoice, computerChioce)
{
    if (userChoice === computerChioce)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    else if (userChoice === "rock")
    {
        if(computerChioce === "scissors")
        {
            return "rock wins" + " ," + "rock breaks scissors";
        }
        else if (computerChioce === "paper")
        {
            return "paper wins" +  " ,"  + "paper captures rock";
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "paper")
    {
        if (computerChioce === "rock")
        {
            return "paper wins" +  ", "  + "paper captures rock";
        }
        else if (computerChioce === "scissors")
        {
            return "scissors win" + ", " + "scissors cuts paper";
        }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "scissors")
    {
        if (computerChioce === "rock")
        {
            return "rock wins" + " " + "rock breaks scissors";
        }
        else if (computerChioce === "paper")
        {
            return "scissors win" + ", " + "scissors cuts paper";
        }
    }
};

console.log("You chose" + " " + userChoice + ".");
console.log("Computer chose" + " " + computerChoice + ".");
compare (userChoice, computerChoice);
```